# Automatic "Possible duplicate" is definitely duplicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

In [Are programmers overly-dependent on their tools? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477018/are-programmers-overly-dependent-on-their-tools-closed) (10k only), there's two cases of

```
Possible Duplicate:
Are we as programmers becoming too dependent on our IDEs?
```

Comment: From the revision history it looks like the the first simply wasn't removed after the question was reopened.

Comment: I've edited it, so here's a link to the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3477018/revisions) instead :-p

Answer (score 6):

We have since completely changed how this works - it is no longer in the post body.  As a result, duplicates HTML blocks in the body will no longer be possible.

...at least not by the system, you could add something that looks like it still, if you're bored :)