# Ironic? Closed as "Duplicate" is duplicated

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic “Possible duplicate” is definitely duplicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/automatic-possible-duplicate-is-definitely-duplicated)

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883000/how-to-design-the-asp-net-page-to-support-all-multiple-screen-resolutions/4883136#4883136) closed as duplicate, but the note displaying the source question is shown twice. And yes I tested, both links go to the same question.

[image: what's up with that?]

Comment: Apparently this question is itself [a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/automatic-possible-duplicate-is-definitely-duplicated), heh.

Comment: However true this is, I would have never found it to be a duplicate based on the fact that the wording doesn't support the concept, and also the links are now 404'd - at least I was courteous enough to take a screenshot ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was closed as a duplicate, reopened, then closed as a duplicate again. Since the notification is just part of the post body, there's nothing to prevent it from being added multiple times in cases where the question is closed as a duplicate more than once. This is undesirable, but probably not a scenario that comes up often enough that it can't just be manually corrected.

In fact, it seems that Robert Harvey tried to [roll back the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4883000/revisions) that added in the second notification, but your tag edit collided with the rollback and reinserted it.