# Community♦ adds extra "Possible Duplicate" block to question closed again as dupe

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, community-user

I noticed Marc closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930333/what-is-the-use-of-creating-properties-for-a-variable-closed) as a dupe, then found a better question to close it as a dupe of so he reopened and closed it again.

Community♦ then proceeds to add an extra dupe block above the existing one ([this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/883e685f-2e40-4c04-af5a-ac8b5e87a58f/view-source)):

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [Should I use public properties and private fields or public fields for data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->

> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [C#: Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

This may be expected or unexpected behavior, but any idea if we can get it to add to the existing list instead?

BTW, [I've taken the time to merge both blockquotes together by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ce72edf4-6789-4d73-84ed-e77316f9ed31/view-source):

```
> **Possible Duplicates:**  
> [Should I use public properties and private fields or public fields for data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data)  
> [C#: Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

Comment: Voting to reopen so we can close it with the right banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a question is closed as a duplicate that text is added to the top.  So if the question is closed twice it may have the message twice. There are some other questions on Meta about this:

[Automatic "Possible duplicate" is definitely duplicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/automatic-possible-duplicate-is-definitely-duplicated)