# Possibly duplicate possible duplicate?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I saw this today:

[image: Possibly duplicate possible duplicate]

Note the two, identical apart from capitalization, "Possible duplicate" labels. I checked, and they point to *exactly* the same link. I realize that this follows the same sort of idea as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/automatic-possible-duplicate-is-definitely-duplicated) (and I realize that that's kind of ironic) but I know for a fact this question was not re-opened, and even if it were, why the difference in capitalization and spacing?

Also, I can't be sure with that question, because the question in question has (questionably?) since been removed.

Sorry if this is some feature I just don't know about.

Comment: If you link to the question you should see the second duplicate listing being a normal edit

Comment: Looks like someone tried to dupe the dupe header, but he got lost in recursion and couldn't get the line break right.

Comment: Any reason nobody edited it out in the years that passed? Two moderators, one high rep user... sigh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A user edited in the duplicate post about 16 seconds before the last vote to close came in.

I'm not sure why he felt the need to jump the gun, but when it was closed the community user added the real duplicate link.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7086524/revisions

Comment: If you look at the markdown it looks like the user actually added the correct one (including the "autogenerated" comment), and then Community added the broken one after it. I'm not sure if Community just got confused by the existing box, but that seems like a bug

Comment: Hey now, don't expect me to actually investigate the issue in a thorough manner. My job is to jump to conclusions, then present them as seeming fact so the masses can overlook reality and satisfy themselves with a quick read.